# Add 2 arraylists into 1 with same index value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I know this question is kind of repetitive But still I can't get an answer.

I have 2 arraylists containing name and description respectively as

```
    final ArrayList<String> arrayOne = new ArrayList<String>(); // containing names
    final ArrayList<String> arraytwo = new ArrayList<String>(); // containing description
```

I need a view like

[image]

I have tried

```
arraytwo.add(arrayOne);
```

&

```
arrayThree.addAll(arrayOne);
arrayThree.addAll(arrayTwo);
```

But can't a desired arraylist.

Regards

Comment: Are the size of arrayone and arraytwo same?

Comment: create a `POJO` with two member variables `name` and `description` and then create a custom `ArrayList<YourPojo>` it would be easy to manage that way,

Comment: they are of same size @NongthonbamTonthoi

Comment: Yes i was going to write about POJO

Comment: use hashmap instead of arraylist to merge two arraylist

Comment: can you elaborate about pojo @SatyenUdeshi

Comment: can you guys provide me some code so that i can take a reference from that.

Comment: @Atula `POJO` means creating a `model` class that holds both `name` and `description`, with its `Getter` and `Setter` methods , you can find one simple example here : http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: @Atula please check my answer with POJO class

Comment: as per the answers below, its better to use Hashmap or POJO better than joining two array, then when try to read you have to manipulate index, which is tricky and may cause exceptions, i.e `array.get(i), array.get(i + (array.size()/2))` .. etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POJO class

```
public class Model
{
    String name;
    String desc;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        desc = desc;
    }
    }
```

For Storing to arraylist

```
ArrayList<Model> arrayModel = new ArrayList<Model>();

      for(int i=0;i<arrayOne.size();i++)
   {
        Model model=new Model();
        model.setName(arrayOne.get(i));
        model.setDesc(arrayTwo.get(i));
        arrayModel.add(model);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to create POJO, try this:

```
List<String> nameList;
List<String> desList;

//for storing
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<nameList.size();i++) {
    map.put(nameList.get(i), desList.get(i));
}

//for retrieving
for(Map.Entry<String, String> m : map.entrySet())
    String nameListItem = m.getKey();
    String desListItem = m.getValue();
}
```